# Run node.js script from cron fails, manual works fine

Tags: node.js, cron

I am trying to run a script from cron on boot; I have seen many references to Path vars but none have helped my situation.

The cron:

```
@reboot /home/pi/nodestart.sh
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/pi/Public/abc/
source $HOME/.profile
NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
sleep 2
nodemon app.js < /dev/null >/home/pi/startup.log 2>/home/pi/startup.err &
```

Note that I have used every combination of relative and absolute paths

Here is the error log (when running from cron):

```
pi@dev:~ $ cat startup.err 
module.js:471
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'sugar'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Public/abc/logutil.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

It seems that it finds other modules shown below:

```
//app.js
var express             = require('express');
var logger = require('tracer').colorConsole();
var fs                  = require('fs');
var multer              = require('multer');
var app                 = express();
var async               = require('async');
var bodyParser          = require('body-parser'); 
var ejs                 = require('ejs'); 
const clientSessions    = require("client-sessions");
var db                  = require('./dbutil');
var log                 = require('./logutil');
var passThru            = require('stream').PassThrough;
var Sugar               = require('sugar');
```

any ideas?

Comment: how were the modules installed?  Is sugar a global install?

Comment: globally, sorry! sudo npm install sugar -g

Comment: whats the path of NodeJs

Comment: NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/nodejs

Comment: hmm that's set up different than my install. is sugar in the folder: /usr/lib/node_modules

Comment: pi@dev:/usr/lib/node_modules $ ls
bower    graceful-fs  localtunnel  minimatch  npm
forever  http-server  lodash       nodemon    sugar

Comment: I don't really know - but that list of modules doesn't match up with what you are requiring in your code.  I bet there is another node_modules path somewhere where this library should be installed. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138163/discussion-between-phpmydev-and-akaphenom).

Answer (score 0):

Sugar (and a few other modules, once I got past Sugar) was not in the right place.  I'm not sure how to describe where they should go, but I put them in /home/pi/node_modules - this did the trick, the cron runs fine now on reboot.